# Android: App shows xml file data in emulator but not in device

Tags: android, xml, android-permissions

I have an app that performs its task from xml file and the file is in /data/data/my.package/files/test.xml. The data is easily extracted from the xml file in the emulator but in the real device there is no data all.

I thought there might me the permission problem and I have set permission for these

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

But also there is no data display in the real device. The app is completely running good in the emulator.

Any help would be really appreciable.

Comment: Try to put your xml file in assert folder and access from assert path.

Comment: What about connecting the Cellphone to your computer and debug with LogCat?

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres It runs with no error.

Comment: @Haresh The xml files is created as response comes from the server so as to work in offline mode.

Comment: have you store this xml file in specific location ?

Comment: @Haresh By default the file is created in the above mentioned directory

Comment: @Haresh I mean connect your cell phone with an USB cable to the computer and activate the debug mode.

Comment: can you please try to store in sdcard if sdcard is not avilable then try to store in internal storage ?

Comment: `in the real device there is no data all` ? What do you mean with that? Is the xml file there? Is it's size/length 0 ? Be clear please. And post some relevant code. Did your app download that file or created one from scratch?